# Laravel how to response only 204 code status with no body message

Tags: php, laravel

I am using

```
return response(null,204);
```

because I would like to return an empty body message, but the problem is that when I parse the response with a ruby code

```
JSON.parse(res.body)
```

I get some body message:

```
{"data"=>[]}
```

so how can I avoid to return this "data" and instead return only the status code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try `return Response::make("", 204);`

Update:
[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571579/mark)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913182/156746) is more up to date:

```
use response;

return response()->noContent()
```

Comment: I still have a error in controller: 
Error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found in file...
because that need to import it then 
```use response;``` resolve for me.

Comment: Little tip, noContent() also takes a status code, e.g.: `return response()->noContent(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)`

Answer (score 62):

You can also do `return response()->noContent();`

Comment: You don't need to put 204, just noContent() is enough

Answer (score 20):

You may return null:

```
return response(null, 204);
```

Edit: I didn't read the question before answering and I notice now that you are already doing this. I recommend you just do an empty / null check on the body in your Ruby code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is return `null` with response code. For example

```
return response(null, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
# or with json
return response()->json(null, Response::HTTP_CREATED)
```

Comment: it  errors with `Class http\Env\Response' not found`

Comment: You need importing before using:v

Comment: For 204: return response()->json(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT)